# Knockout.js event undefined in subscriber Firefox

Tags: firefox, knockout.js

When I subscribe to an observable named "degree", I want use event.target in the callback to get the DOM element that triggered the change event.  This works in Chrome but in Firefox I get "event is not defined"

```
 self.degree.subscribe(function(degree){
  console.log(event.target);
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

The `subscribe` API does not pass an `event` to the callback. In some browsers (like Firefox), `event` does not live on `window` and is only accessible as an argument to the event handler.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could do:

```
<input data-bind="event: { change: myHandler }" />
```

Then, define a handler:

```
myHandler: function(data, event) {
     //do something
}
```

However, accessing DOM elements in the view model is generally not a good pattern in Knockout. [Custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) are a good way to make the connection between view model changes and your DOM elements.